# Converting `false` into `nil`

Tags: ruby, null

When you want to convert a varible `v` into `false` when it is `nil`/`false` and `true` otherwise, there is an easy way to do it:

```
!!v
```

But is there an easy way to convert `v` into `nil` when it is `nil`/`false` and retain its value otherwise?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `||=`:

```
a = 'hello'
a ||= nil #=> "hello"

a = true
a ||= nil #=> true

a = false
a ||= nil #=> nil

a = nil
a ||= nil #=> nil
```

Comment: is there also a solution in case I don't want to place it into a variable?

Comment: Then you can just use `|| nil`. E.g. `false || nil #=> nil`